# Android: Can't access cursor data inside ContentProvider using CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

Currently i'm starting in Android development and i want to learn how to develop apps and apply good rules and recommendations. Somewhere i read that the right thing is to use CursorLoader to load lists to load data asynchronous in the view. Previously, thanks to a tutorial i created a simple app that shows a list of data in a SQLite database table, with a custom Adapter that i extended from SimpleCursorAdapter to show different icons basing on the value of a certain field of each row of the query (cursor). The code of my custom adapter is the next:

```
public class MarcaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context ctx; 
private Cursor cur;

public MarcaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, 0);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.cur = c;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.template_marcas, null);
    View row = convertView;

    ImageView imgRk = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipoRanking);
    //Dependiendo del ranking, cargaremos la imagen de mario o de wario
    if(cur.getInt(3) % 2 == 0)
        imgRk.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1_pressed);
    else
        imgRk.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1_focus);

    return row;
} }
```

And the content of template_marcas.xml is the next:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
android:background="#002EB8"
android:paddingTop="20dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nomMarca"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView69"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nomMarca"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nomMarca"
    android:text=" es la numero "
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rankMarca"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView69"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView69"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tipoRanking"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView69"
    android:layout_marginRight="56dp" /></RelativeLayout>
```

So, in order to use CursorLoader and ContentProvider, i converted my normal class that had a method to query the table to get a cursor of that table, i extended from ContentProvider and registered in the manifest file, the class is the next:

```
public class MarcaDAO extends ContentProvider {

private ConnHandler conn;
SQLiteDatabase dbObj;

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    conn = new ConnHandler(getContext());
    dbObj = conn.getDb();
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cur = dbObj.query("MARCA", projection, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cur;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}}
```

conn and dbObj objets are used to manage connection, those object works. And finally, i have the Activity which implements LoaderCallbacs with the overriden methods and initializing the CursorLoader:

```
public class MarcaActivity extends Activity implements
```

LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {

```
//MarcaDAO dao;
MarcaCursorAdapter crsAdap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_marca);

    final ListView lstMarcas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstMarcas);
    //Sacamos los datos de las marcas para mostrarlos en el listview
    //dao = new MarcaDAO(this);
    //Cursor cur = dao.getList();
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    crsAdap = new MarcaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.template_marcas, null , 
            new String[]{"hip_nombre", "hip_ranking"}, new int[]{R.id.nomMarca, R.id.rankMarca});
    lstMarcas.setAdapter(crsAdap);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.marca, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, Uri.parse("content://com.example.crudapp.marcaData"),
            new String[]{"_id", "hip_nombre", "hip_codigo", "hip_ranking"}, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    crsAdap.swapCursor(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    crsAdap.swapCursor(null);
}}
```

But, when i run the application (4.2.2) i get a NullPointerException in the method getView of MarcaCursorAdapter in this line:

```
if(cur.getInt(3) % 2 == 0)
```

Because the cursor row values are null, and if i remove this code, the list loads the exact number of rows but with no values (the textviews nomMarca and rankMarca are empty) so i don't know what i'm doing wrong. Previously it worked without content provider and without cursorloader but i wanna develop good code so i changed my classes.

Regards.

UPDATE: By the way, i forgot to say, if in the Activity instead using MarcaCursorAdapter i just use SimpleCursorAdapter (losing the customization of my method getView) the list loads without problems and showing the data, so i think that my problem is in the way that i coded my MarcaCursorAdapter class, but i don't know what's the mistake.

Regards again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because the cursor row values are null,

The `Cursor` values aren't null(or at least this isn't the reason for the error) it's the `cur` reference that is null. When you first initialize the adapter you do it with a null `Cursor`(at this point `cur` is null). When your loader does its job and loads the data you call `swapCursor()` and the adapter will start building rows, unfortunately your `cur` reference will continue to be null as it doesn't get magically updated with the new `Cursor` reference.

> By the way, i forgot to say, if in the Activity instead using
>   MarcaCursorAdapter i just use SimpleCursorAdapter (losing the
>   customization of my method getView) the list loads without problems
>   and showing the data,

This is happening because of your implementation of the `getView()` method. First of all, for Cursor based adapter you'd want to override the two method responsible for building a row `newView()`(create the actual row view) and `bindView()`(bind the previously built row view with Cursor data). If all you want to do is change that image resource then you have two choices:

- Use a `ViewBinder` on your adapter(recommended).
- Extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override only it's `bindView()` method:

  ```
  //...
  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      super.bindView(view, context, cursor); // let the default implementation populate our views
      // change the image
      ImageView imgRk = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tipoRanking);
      //Dependiendo del ranking, cargaremos la imagen de mario o de wario
      if(cursor.getInt(3) % 2 == 0) {
         imgRk.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1_pressed);
      } else {
         imgRk.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1_focus);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it worked. Well, a couple of hours before reading your answer, i started reading about newView, bindView and getView, and i tried with newView and it worked, in the next way:

```
@Override 
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.template_marcas, null);
    ImageView imgRk = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tipoRanking);
    //Dependiendo del ranking, cargaremos la imagen de mario o de wario
    if(getCursor().getInt(3) % 2 == 0)
        imgRk.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1_pressed);
    else
        imgRk.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1_focus);

    return view;
}
```

But, i am not too much clear about when i have to use newView and when i have to use bindView or which one is more optimal in my application. But i'm going to search about your piece of advice of using ViewBinder if is better in performance or development meanings.

Regards.

Comment: Your change is small so a `ViewBinder` is more appropriate(and easier) to use. Those two methods are responsible together for building the row. If you're happy with the default implementation of one of them then you could get away with just implementing the other one.

Comment: But, there's a difference in overriding newView or bindView?
Regards.

Comment: Yes, they serve different purposes. One builds the row and one binds the data. You wouldn't want to mix that together.